# 'graphic-design' tag shouldn't exist

Tags: discussion, tagging

I see no point having [graphic-design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphic-design), because all the questions should be relevant to the site's title. I see it as probably the severest form of [meta-tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Even if the "graphic" should disappear from the title, "graphic-design" probably wouldn't ever work as a lone tag — it might in rare cases, but for the most part its relevancy should be evaluated.

NB: the tag is cleaned now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we get the scope of the site changed, the graphic-design tag will be necessary to differentiate those questions from other design questions. It's a meta-tag now, but it won't be in the future. I say we just keep it in the system.

Comment: I wouldn't say the tag *will be necessary*, but it surely *might* if the question deals with the "graphic design" as a whole. Wouldn't use it *only* for *rough categorization*, it's hard to come up with a question that would need *only* the graphic-design tag. But yes: blacklisting is too much.

Answer (score 5):

This has been marked as an intrinsic tag - it won't block inbound migrations, but no one will be able to use it.